# From Uri to Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM

Tags: java, android, uri, environment

A user chooses a directory through the following code:

```
public void startChoose(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), 8010);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      switch (requestCode) {
        case 8010:
            mypath = data.getData().toString();
            break;
    }
}
```

His directory is stored in `mypath` as following (e.g. with DCIM):

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADCIM
```

Now, is it possible to go from `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADCIM` to `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`and how?

Asked differently, I would like to get the variable `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` for `mypath` when the User chooses the DCIM directory. How can one do that?

Comment: Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM=="DCIM"

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)==/storage/emulated/0/DCIM

Comment: You are asking for the cursed function getRealPathFromUri().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, is it possible to go from content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADCIM to Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIMand how?

No. The `Uri` that you get back does not have to correspond to a file (e.g., it points to a document in Google Drive). Even if it corresponds to a file, it does not have to reside in a directory that is tied to `Environment` (e.g., it points to a file in a custom directory).

Please just use the `Uri`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Good to know that it is not possible. I have a code part that uses `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` i.e. `File imagedir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);`. Is it then possible to have it use `mypath` as a Uri like this: `File imagedir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mypath);`? I tried `File imagedir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mypath.toString());` but this does not work.

Comment: @Sam77: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is a method on `Environment`. It does not take arbitrary values as parameters.

Comment: I see. I must rethink my code in that case. Thanks for your help.